# Creating planning unit shape to use with Marxan?

Tags: qgis

There used to be a tool in the old QMarxan plugin to create the planning unit shapefile but the new version QMarxan Toolbox no longer has this tool.

Any ideas on how to create the planning unit shapefile using QGIS?

Comment: What's a planning unit shapefile?

Comment: I figured out how to do it and it is quite simple and basic. It can be done using the create grid tool in the Research Tools.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it and it is quite simple and basic. It can be done using the create grid tool in the Research Tools